# Skip $asyncValidators until model is dirty

Tags: angularjs

I use `$asyncValidators` to validate a field value. The field value is fetched from server with `$resource`. On page load, the value is empty and the validator sends a request to the server. When `$resource` has fetched the resource, the field value is populated and the validator sends another request to the server.

I would like to skip these two initial requests since they are useless. How do I do that?

My input field:

```
<input name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" validate-name>
```

My directive:

```
angular.module('myapp').directive('validateName', function($http, $q) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$asyncValidators.name = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        return $http.post('/validate-username', {username: viewValue}).then(function(response) {
          if (!response.data.validUsername) {
            return $q.reject(response.data.errorMessage);
          }
          return true;
        });
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reasonable condition is for the model to be touched; if it isn't, just return a resolved promise, without accessing the server. I.e.:

```
ctrl.$asyncValidators.name = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
    if( ctrl.$touched ) {
        return $http.post('/validate-username', {username: viewValue})....
    }
    else {
        return $q.resolve(true);
    }
};
```